# Apache Spark RDD Split "|"

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to produce a formatted CSV file from pipe("|") delimited file using Apache Spark . input file contains:

> apple|ball|cat
>
> Blacktown| Bela vista| Greenacre
>
> x|y|z

I am trying with:

```
val name= sc.textFile(input.txt")
val split=name.map(line=>line.split("|")).map( x => (x(0),x(2)) )
split.foreach(println)
```

Output:

> (x,y)
>
> (a,p)
>
> (B,a)

My required output is:

> (apple,cat)
>
> (Blacktown, Greenacre)
>
> (x,z)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `String` argument for `split` function is a regular expression so if you want to use pipe it has to be escaped:

```
line.split("\\|")
```

otherwise it is interpreted as an alternation between two empty patterns.

You can also use [variant which accepts `Character` literal](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#split(separator:Char):Array[String]):

```
line.split('|')
```

or [an `Array` of `Character` literals](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#split(separators:Array[Char]):Array[String]):

```
line.split(Array('|'))
```

It is also better to validate the input:

```
names.map(_.split("\\|")).collect {
  case Array(x, _, y) => (x, y)
}
```